# Rate of convergence for a generic function sequence at a point

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

Consider a sequence of functions $f_k:(0,\infty)\mapsto(0,\infty)$ and a rate sequence $r_k \downarrow 0$. Assume that the functions are uniformly bounded from above by a constant $M$, i.e. $\Vert f_k \Vert_\infty<M$, and that, for all positive constants $C>0$, $\lim_{k\to \infty}f_k(C)/r_k$ exists (finite). Can we then conclude that there exists a sequence $C_k\to \infty$ which diverges "not too fast" such that $f_k(C_k)/r_k=O(1)$?

I was trying to derive a positive answer by contradiction, but I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n(i)$ be increasing such that $r_k < \frac{1}{i}$ if $k > n(i)$.

For $k \in [n(i), n(i + 1))$, define
$$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
r_k \cdot x, & x < k\\
r_k \cdot k, & x \geq k 
\end{cases}$$

Then each $f_k(x) \leq 1$.

$f_k(x) / r_k = x$ for $x < k$ so $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}f_k(C) / r_k$ exists for any $C$.

For $x \geq r_k$ we have $f_k(x) / r_k = k$. Thus we have $f_k(x) / r_k \geq
 \min(k, x)$.

So for any $C_k \to \infty$ we have $f_k(C_k) / r_k \geq \min(k, C_k) \to \infty$ and thus $f_k(C_k) / r_k \neq O(1)$ for any $C_k \to \infty$.